# I can not create within the a layout-small folder a xml file

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have android studio 1.3.1 and I have a problem in creating a `xml` file within the `layout-small` or `layout-normal` and etc.

For example when I right click on the `res` folder and I can create a `layout-small`. But after from that, I have no the `layout-small` folder still in the android studio but I have it in within the `res` folder in my project. for more information please see the following image:

[image]

[image]

With this condition, I can not design for other screen sizes!!!  Are there a solution for this problem.

Comment: restart android studio or sync project :D

Comment: I have an answer.Please see that and say your opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Studio support multiple view for project structure. By default "Android" view is selected. "Android" view display files by combining with resource type. 
To see all files as directory listing we need to switch to "Project Files" view.

Click "Android" and from popup select "Project Files"

Answer (score -1):

I think in android 1.3.1 somethings is different. For example in older version of the android studio we can not create two `xml` layout with a similar names in a folder, and we should create separate folders for each `layout-small` size and etc. But I think in android 1.3.1 we can create two `xml` file  with a similar names in a folder. Please see the following image and say if I wrong.

[image]